# The Yoshida approximation of a PDE

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am studying an PDE which has the form
$$
u-u_0 = \alpha\operatorname{div}\left(\frac{\nabla u}{|\nabla u|}\right) \tag 1
$$
for $u_0\in BV(\Omega)$, $\alpha>0$ a constant.

Let's denote by $u_\alpha$ the solution of $(1)$.

I am trying to study the properties of $u_\alpha$ via the Yoshida approximation. For instance, I was told that I can write
$$
u_\alpha = (I+\alpha A)^{-1}u_0
$$
where $A$ is a linear operator and has some other nice properties. Also, I was told I can show that $\alpha\to\|u_\alpha\|_{L^2}$ is convex and decreasing by using the properties of Yoshida approximation.

However, I really got confused that how I even get start. In my understanding, should I have 
$$
Au = \operatorname{div}\left(\frac{\nabla u}{|\nabla u|}\right)
$$
right? But how could it be linear? and, what properties can I have for $A$?

Thank you!

PS: I learned the Yoshida approximation from [Brezis](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387709130) book, chapter 7.